Is it possible for a PageView.builder to have a dynamic width on each page?
I'm making an AirBnb-style options selector, I already have the desired effect when I scroll, but I can't get each element to have a dynamic size. By setting the viewportFraction: 0.26 I end up with something similar to what I want, but it is not presentable.
Any recommendation?
I already tried with a Carousel, a ListView.builder, but it is not the same as with the PageView.Builder.
Update
I attach an image of what I currently have.


You can wrap with Align widget

whats not working with ListView.builder?

It would be helpful to answer if you could attach screenshot.

@MuhammadAliRaza Capture added.

@pskink Because I don't need a simple ListView.builder. I need to be able to have a positioning on each item, have you seen the AirBnb app? Although if you know how to do it with that Widget, please explain to me.
